# Testing of App on Tablet, Android

Tags: android, tablet

I need to create application for Tablet, Android. I never create app fot Tablet, only mobile with Android. How can I create emulator for tablet testing? And 1 thing - I need to know a width of screen for logotype creating - what screen size Tablet have?

Comment: Only check it out this link, I hope you get every thing about Testing of App on Tablet and Screen size of Tablet . http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a tablet emulator, just create an AVD using Android 3.0, 3.1 or 3.2 -- this should automatically get you a WXGA (1280x800) screen.

For tablet screen sizes, check out  [Supporting Multiple Screens: Configuration Examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples) from the Android documentation:

- 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
- 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
- 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
- 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Most tablets will be in the 7” and 10” range.

Comment: That depends on how you hold the device. In portrait mode, the screen would be 720px/800px wide and 1280px high, in landscape it would be 1280px wide and 720px/800px high.

Comment: As a concrete example, the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 is 1280x800 in its natural landscape orientation: http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytab/10.1/spec.html

Comment: Good, concise answer. Will buy again.

Answer (score 3):

First, create fluid layout, so your application will fit any screen size

- [How to create Liquid Layout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693148/how-to-create-liquid-layout-in-android)
- http://envyandroid.com/archives/227/stretching-and-spanning-layouts

Second, in android emulator you can change screen size (in settings of ADV)

- [How do I change screen orientation in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991318/how-to-change-emulator-screen-orientation)
- [How to resize the AVD emulator (in Eclipse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359895/android-emulator-screen-too-tall)
- http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Third, screen size to set you can get in technical details of tablet

- GalaxyPad 1280x800 (http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytab/10.1/spec.html)
- Motorola XOOM 1280x800 (http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Tablets/ci.MOTOROLA-XOOM-with-WiFi-US-EN.alt)
- and many more, depends on your choice

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Just use the `android` tool to download the SDK for Android 3.0+ (r11 for example) and create an emulator like you would normally.

Note that the 3.0+ emulators like to crash from time to time from my expirience.